# why is "arp -a" showing inconsistent outputs that are vastly different?

Tags: arp

I have newly set up a computer with Ubuntu 18.04 and connected to my home wifi. When I try `arp -a` command to scan other devices connected to the same network, I see some very weird outputs.

First, the connect is fine by checking `ifconfig`:

```
john@home:~$ ifconfig 
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 246054  bytes 21958490 (21.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 246054  bytes 21958490 (21.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.14  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::e3f:e0a5:2438:a96a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 240d:1a:6a5:c900:1420:b3cc:994b:1b7b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 240d:1a:6a5:c900:74f4:f504:3a41:bc12  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 04:33:c2:c4:02:a2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2452125  bytes 3302288691 (3.3 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 964749  bytes 117659686 (117.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

It has the ip address of 192.168.1.14
Then I tried `arp -a`:

```
john@home:~$ arp -a 
? (192.168.1.19) at 92:c4:78:3c:46:16 [ether] on wlo1
_gateway (192.168.1.1) at e4:7e:66:1f:bf:4c [ether] on wlo1
? (192.168.1.5) at 26:36:46:f9:69:83 [ether] on wlo1
```

which makes sense because I can confirm that my ipad has ip address of `192.168.1.19` and my phone has ip address of `192.168.1.5`

However, after a while I executed `arp -a` again, and the output blows my mind:

```
john@home:~$ arp -a 
? (192.168.1.206) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.183) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.107) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.8) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.18) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.165) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.186) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.110) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.77) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.33) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.178) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.123) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.112) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.96) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.117) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.74) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.95) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.84) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.41) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.62) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.51) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.8) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.29) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.18) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.231) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.252) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.241) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.198) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.219) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.208) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.165) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.186) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.143) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.132) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.153) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.110) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.99) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.120) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.77) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.66) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.87) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.44) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.33) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.54) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.11) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.21) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.234) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.244) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.201) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.222) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.211) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.168) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.189) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.178) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.135) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.156) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.145) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.102) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.123) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.112) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.69) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.90) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.47) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.36) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.57) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.3) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.24) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.237) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.226) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.247) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.204) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.193) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.214) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.171) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.160) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.181) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.138) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.159) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.148) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.105) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.126) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.115) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.72) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.93) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.82) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.39) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.60) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.49) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.6) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.27) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.16) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.229) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.250) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.207) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.196) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.217) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.174) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.163) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.184) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.141) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.130) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.151) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.108) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.97) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.118) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.75) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.64) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.85) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.42) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.63) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.52) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.9) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.30) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.19) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.232) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.253) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.242) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.199) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.220) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.209) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.166) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.187) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.176) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.133) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.154) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.111) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.100) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.121) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.78) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.67) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.88) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.45) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.34) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.55) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.12) at <incomplete> on wlo1
_gateway (192.168.1.1) at e4:7e:66:1f:bf:4c [ether] on wlo1
? (192.168.1.22) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.235) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.224) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.245) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.202) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.223) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.212) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.169) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.190) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.179) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.136) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.157) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.146) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.103) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.124) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.113) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.70) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.91) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.80) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.37) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.58) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.15) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.4) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.25) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.238) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.227) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.248) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.205) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.194) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.215) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.172) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.161) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.182) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.139) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.128) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.149) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.106) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.127) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.116) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.73) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.94) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.83) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.40) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.61) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.50) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.7) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.28) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.17) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.230) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.251) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.240) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.197) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.218) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.175) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.164) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.185) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.142) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.131) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.152) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.109) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.98) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.119) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.76) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.65) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.86) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.43) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.32) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.53) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.10) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.31) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.20) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.233) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.254) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.243) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.200) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.221) at <incomplete> on wlo1
john@home:~$
```

What is this?  What just happened?
I thought `arp -a` is supposed to scan and list other devices on the same network. What are these results?

Comment: Try `ip route flush cache`. See also [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192313/how-do-you-clear-the-arp-cache-on-linux).

Answer (score 1):

> I thought `arp -a` is supposed to scan and list other devices on the same network.

`arp -a` does not scan. It only displays the kernel's IPv4 network neighbour cache. Any entry in the output is there because it was already in the cache, not because you run `arp`.

> What are these results?

An incomplete entry means a request has been sent to discover the MAC address of a network neighbour for a given IP address, but no reply has been received (yet). Either there will be a valid reply in a moment, so the entry will become complete and it will remain in the cache for a while; or there will be no valid reply and the incomplete entry will soon be removed from the cache.

> What just happened?

Something in your OS has just tried to access all these IP addresses. It could have been an actual scanner, e.g. `nmap 192.168.1.0/24`.

An incomplete entry that doesn't turn complete will go away eventually, unless your OS tries to access the relevant IP address periodically. A new access attempt will make the entry reappear; or it will prevent it from disappearing in the first place.

If it's you who run (or keeps running) a scanner or like then there's nothing to worry about. The posted output from `arp -a` is normal. Even if `arp -a` prints only a few entries now, this will print many:

```
nmap 192.168.1.0/24; arp -a
```

If it's not you then it's worth investigating. The fact your network has been scanned from your OS without your knowledge may or may not indicate the OS has been compromised.